# Using the Android support library to support older

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app and have been looking around a bit on how to support older versions(I've been developing for 4.0 while 10% of the phones are on 2.2 and 50% on 2.3). I've [found the support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and wanted to see if I understood things correctly.

1. I get the support library for version 2.2.
2. I switch from using the stuff from the normal .jar to the one from
   the support library. Seems to be a bit of code changes and new imports.
3. My app is now working on Android 2.2

Comment: So you want us to tell you that your already working app is already working?  Or you want a comprehensive checklist?  Or you simply want a yes or no answer?

Comment: it's working on 4.0, I'm looking into what's the easiest way of making it work on 2.2, hence my little checklist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've found the support library and wanted to see if I understood things correctly

Steps 1 and 2 are fine. Depending on your starting point, you may have intervening steps before Step 3, such as adjusting `android:minSdkVersion` to support API Level 8 (Android 2.2). And, depending on what else you may want to use (e.g., ActionBarSherlock for a consistent action bar pattern), you may have more steps to add.